# Added css to a div containing img, makes it unclickable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery Mobile, to create a small mobile app. I have a page which includes just a GIF. Though the GIF can be clickable, to move to the next page. But the point is that the GIF is not full screen in some devices, so I added some CSS to make it full screen, meaning to stretch it, which works, but then it makes the div (or GIF) unclickable. So I cannot click it to move to the next page, you need to wait for the animation to finish.

Here is how the page is defined in HTML:

```
<div id="correctGIF" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="false">
    <img src="images/Correct1.gif">
</div>
```

I added this CSS:

```
#correctGIF {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#correctGIF > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Is there any way, how can I stretch the GIF to make it cover the whole screen, without making it unclickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is z-index problem. Because you set z-index: -1; so that the div is unclickable. Change z-index to postive integer or remove z-index in css

Comment: Yes, that worked. I just removed it completely, the GIF is still full screen, and it is clickable now. Thanks!

Comment: "please change z-index " no need to plead in my opinion.. you're giving free help :)